# Rspec: Stubbing out a where statement in a controller test

Tags: testing, rspec, controller

I'm writing the following test:

```
    let!(:city_areas) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:city_area, 30) }

    before {
        @city_areas = mock_model(CityArea)
        CityArea.should_receive(:where).and_return(city_areas)
    }

    it 'should assign the proper value to city areas variable' do
        get :get_edit_and_update_vars
        assigns(:city_areas).should eq(city_areas.order("name ASC"))
    end
```

to test the following method:

```
def get_edit_and_update_vars
    @city_areas = CityArea.where("city_id = '#{@bar.city_id}'").order("name ASC").all
end
```

However, it fails out, saying that there's no method 'city_id' for nil:NilClass, leading me to believe it's still attempting to use the instance variable @bar.

How do I properly stub out this where statement to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing @city_areas = mock_model(CityArea) and then you never use @city_areas again?

I would test it this way:

inside the model CityArea create a named scope for this: where("city_id = '#{@bar.city_id}'").order("name ASC")

then in your controller spec you do

```
describe 'GET get_edit_and_update_vars' do
  before(:each) do
    @areas = mock('areas')
  end

  it 'gets the areas' do
    CityArea.should_receive(:your_scope).once.and_return(@areas)
    get :get_edit_and_update_vars
  end

  it 'assign the proper value to city areas variable' do
    CityArea.stub!(:your_scope => @areas)
    get :get_edit_and_update_vars
    assigns(:city_areas).should eq(ordered)
  end
end
```

and you should also create a spec for that new scope on the model spec

just a tip, you shouldn't use should_receive(...) inside the before block, use stub! inside before and use should_receive when you want to test that method is called

also, you shouldn't need to use factorygirl when testing controllers, you should always mock the models, the model can be tested on the model spec

Comment: Yeah, you solution ended up being much cleaner. Thanks for the assist!